# Problems installing Google Protocol Buffers R Package

Tags: r, protocol-buffers

Does anyone have any good ideas why this is is happening? I run R as root. Here is the version:

> version
>                  _
>       platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
>       arch           x86_64
>       os             linux-gnu
>       system         x86_64, linux-gnu
>       status
>       major          3
>       minor          0.1
>       year           2013
>       month          05
>       day            16
>       svn rev        62743
>       language       R
>       version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>       nickname       Good Sport

It seems to get very far. Whether I install the package from source or from package, I get this error:

```
> ** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   ‘RProtoBuf-intro.Rnw’ 
   ‘RProtoBuf-quickref.Rnw’ 
   ‘RProtoBuf-unitTests.Rnw’ 
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/RProtoBuf/libs/RProtoBuf.so':
  /usr/lib64/R/library/RProtoBuf/libs/RProtoBuf.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf2io18CopyingInputStream4SkipEi
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
*  removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RProtoBuf’
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of the Protocol Buffers library do you have installed?

On Ubuntu, with the default version of Google Protocol Buffers (currently: 2.4.1), it "just works".  The package just checks for a minimal version of 2.2.0.

Comment: I am running on CentOS release 6.4 (Final). I have protobuf-2.4.1 installed, but I just realized that it is not in /usr/lib64... but in /usr/local/lib. It is on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH though. It seems as if it is looking for the very same library it is building?

Comment: You need to look at the configure output, and the actual link step (which you didn't show) and try to fix accordingly.  We do ask `pkg-config --libs protobuf` during the configure run...

Comment: did you try to add this into .bashrc `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` and then restart R Studio? By default, protobuf lib will be installed to /usr/local.

Comment: Every non-brain-dead system has `/usr/local/lib` in the default `ld.conf` path, but maybe `sudo ldconfig` needs to run to refresh the cache...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I resolved by following the note for configuring the protobuf library.

`./configure --prefix=/usr`

https://github.com/google/protobuf : Its under "Hint on install locations".